# Reproducibility Between Remote and Local Computer

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I am currently using `R`, `RStudio`, and a remote computer (using an `R` script) to run the same code. I start by using `set.seed(123)` in all three versions of the code, then using `glmnet` to assess a matrix. Ultimately, I am having trouble reproducing the results between my local and the remote computer's results. I am using `R version 4.0.2` locally, and `R version 3.6.0` remote.

After running several tests, I'm wondering if there is a difference between the two versions in `R` which may lead to slightly different coefficients. If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not output the next, say, million values of R's RNG on both machines and compare the files?

Comment: sorry, but do you know how I could do that? I'd be happy to try. I went into the terminal of the remote computer and ran `set.seed(123)` and `rnorm(3)` and got the same as in my `RStudio` console.

Comment: Something like `set.seed(17); writeLines(sprintf("%15.8a", runif(1e6)), "tmp.txt")` will do the trick.

Comment: Since I'm using `rnorm()` in my original code would it make a difference to use that instead of `runif`? and is there a particular reason for using `sprintf`? Lastly, I presume this would directly explain the lack of reproducibility? By comparing the two results with a `TRUE/FALSE` statement in Excel.

Comment: The purpose is to check that the two RNGs are the same, so use `runif`.  `sprintf` assures us you're seeing all the significant digits, but it's not really necessary: any difference between the two RNGs will quickly create very divergent values.  Please consult the help for "Random" in base `R`.

Comment: I ran both `runif` and `rnorm` to see if there were differences. `runif` gave the same results as my `RStudio` but `rnorm` gave 31316 falses, is this possibly why I'm seeing different results with my local computer compared to the remote computer?

Comment: Yes, that could explain it, depending on the details of the differences represented by those falses.  I vaguely recall reading something about changes in R's RNGs a while ago--consulting the usual `R` discussion groups ought to reveal the details.